# R, split data frame column into 2 on last occurrence of either a + or a - sign

Tags: r, regex, string, split

We are attempting to split 2 dataframe columns using the last occurrence of either a + or - sign, splitting the string immediately before the sign.

What we have

```
zed = data.frame(
  value = c('+23-25', '-23.5+25.5', '-24+24', '-3-6'),
  label = c('p34-150', 'p 243-130', 'p215 +115', 'p215 +115'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

What we are going for

```
output = data.frame(
  value1 = c('+23', '-23.5', '-24', '-3'),
  value2 = c('-25', '+25.5', '+24', '-6'),
  label1 = c('p34', 'p 243', 'p215', 'p215'),
  label2 = c('-150', '-130', '+115', '+115'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

`separate(value, into = c("value1", "value2"), sep = "+|-")` doesn't quite work, `+|-` is an invalid regular expression. `"(?=[+-][^+-]*$)[+-]"` not working as intended either, returns empty columns. At the surface, it seemed like this would be simple but we are struggling.

**Edit:** perhaps this requires a separate posting, but we have a weird issue with an irregular space, causing the good solution below to not work:

```
> zed$Total[1]
[1] "O 239.5−110"
> head(zed %>% separate(Total, into = c("label1", "label2"), sep = "(?=[\\+-][^\\+-]*$)"), 1)
        label1  label2
1  O 239.5−110    <NA>
Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 12 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]. 
> gsub(' ', '', zed$Total[1])
[1] "O 239.5−110"
```

Cannot `gsub` away the space after the O, for some reason this causes the `separate()` to not work.

Comment: I don’t think the irregular space is causing the problem, but just FYI, try using the regex whitespace character class `"\s"`, which will match any whitespace character, instead of `" "` in your `gsub()`. ie, `gsub("\\s", "", zed$Total[1])`.

Comment: makes sense, chatGPT recommended `'[\\s\u00a0]'` to me as I guess this is the specific character that was appearing. `'[\\s\u00a0]'` works but unfortunately `'\\s'` does not work as the first param in the `gsub`

Comment: I'm not familiar with R but rather than splitting could you obtain matches of the (PCRE) regular expression `.*(?=[+-])|(?<=[+-].*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with your last attempt; you just need to escape the `+` and don’t need the `[+-]` at the end.

```
library(tidyr)

zed %>%
  separate(
    value, 
    into = c("value1", "value2"), 
    sep = "(?=[\\+-][^\\+-]*$)"
  ) %>%
  separate(
    label, 
    into = c("label1", "label2"), 
    sep = "(?=[\\+-][^\\+-]*$)"
  )
```

```
  value1 value2 label1 label2
1    +23    -25    p34   -150
2  -23.5  +25.5  p 243   -130
3    -24    +24  p215    +115
4     -3     -6  p215    +115
```

Comment: This is working for one of our columns. In our actual dataframe, for our 2nd column, there in an irregular space character that we cannot remove, that is causing the separate to not work.  See question edit, although this irregular space character is probably for another posting.

Comment: ahh the issue is actually an irregular `−` as well, not just the space.

Comment: The irregular space shouldn’t matter. And you can just add the irregular `−` to the two sets of `[]` in the regex pattern.